# How to have the contents to stay after refreshing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a schedule page and it allows users to put in their events etc on specific date. But the problem is after refreshing, the data will be lost. Any idea how i can solve this problem?

```
enter code hereYUI().use(
'aui-scheduler',
 function(Y) {
  // code goes here
 YUI().use(
'aui-scheduler',
function(Y) {
 var events = [
  {
    content: 'Partial Lunar Eclipse',
    endDate: new Date(2017, 2, 25, 5),
    startDate: new Date(2017, 2, 25, 1)
  },
  {
    color: "#8d8",
    content: 'Earth Day Lunch',
    disabled: true,
    endDate: new Date(2017, 2, 22, 13),
    meeting: true,
    reminder: true,
    startDate: new Date(2017, 2, 22, 12)
  },
  {
    content: "Weeklong",
    endDate: new Date(2017, 2, 27),
    startDate: new Date(2017, 2, 21)
  }
];

var agendaView = new Y.SchedulerAgendaView();
var dayView = new Y.SchedulerDayView();
var weekView = new Y.SchedulerWeekView();
var monthView = new Y.SchedulerMonthView();

var eventRecorder = new Y.SchedulerEventRecorder();

new Y.Scheduler(
  {
    activeView: weekView,
    boundingBox: '#myScheduler',
    date: new Date(2017, 1, 25),
    eventRecorder: eventRecorder,
    items: events,
    render: true,
    views: [dayView, weekView, monthView, agendaView]
   }
   );
  }
  );
  }
  );
```

This was taken from bootstrap.

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: you need a persistent storage either DB or local storage

Comment: you can use `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` which comes with browser it self

Comment: The simplest and most widely supported is WebStorage where you have persistent storage (localStorage) or session based (sessionStorage) which is in memory until you close the browser.

Comment: But how do i do it?

Comment: @LamJunWei Check this out Gist example https://gist.github.com/zaus/4717416 If you cannot understand i can explain you basic stuff on local and session storages

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.sessionStorage`

to set an item

```
window.sessionStorage.setItem('item', value);
```

to get value

```
var itemValue = window.sessionStorage.getItem('item')
```